# force category table refresh when adding new category

Tags: plugins, custom-field

i wonder if there's a relatively easy solution to this :

i have added a custom field to the categories, which in turn gets displayed in the right hand table under its own column name. (essentailly it's a "this category is the default" field.

all works fine, when editing a category.
however, when adding a category with this field(checkbox) selected , all other categories update to "we are not the default anymore". the db also stores these new values as required.

however, as adding a new category is invoked via ajax, the category table on the right hand side does not refresh to reflect these new settings. (only when actually refreshing the whole page , can i actually see the current values)

question is therefore, is there a hook i can plug in to that automatically forces a page refresh after a new category has been added (or better still, just to refresh the table on the right ), or do i actually run a seperate ajax call to get the updated values and update that table ?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Would be better if you showed what code are you working with. Some screenshots would be useful too. You can [edit] your Question whenever needed. Please, mind the  title cases of your sentences too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

actually I managed to solve this differently (and more elegantly).

However, even this new approach had me banging my head against the wall for way too many hours as my option table didn't get updated properly, when doing a bulk delete of more than one category.
Turns out I made two - glaring mistakes .

a) i wrapped a function i needed in when updating the option table ajax into

`if(!defined('DOING_AJAX') || !DOING_AJAX){
//add_action....etc
}`

which didnt help (DOH)

b)I also managed to include the function  that validates  `update_option()` with `require_once()` instead of just `require()` so when using `update_option()` in a loop , it just gave up.

Oh well, maybe someone reads this who's done the same due to lack of sleep/coffee....

Anyway, thanks for trying to help. Next time I'll include code to start off with...

cheers